# Single Pipe "|" with Shift Operators in C function return

Tags: c

Here I have a function that takes a byte, swaps its halves and
returns the result:

```
unsigned char   swap_bits(unsigned char octet)
{
    return ((octet >> 4) | (octet << 4));
}
```

The achieved effect would be as follows:

```
  1 byte
_____________
 0100 | 0001
     \ /
     / \
 0001 | 0100
```

Does the Single Pipe `|` serve as a bitwise OR operator here? How does it collaborate/work with the Shift Operators `<<` and `>>` in this case? Can I replace it with a logical OR operator `||` or anything else? Thanks!

*Edit:* This is my first question on StackOverflow and I received many great answers within a short time. I do appreciate all of them!

Comment: Yes, `|` in C is the bitwise-OR operator (and a binary `&` operator is bitwise-AND, and unary `~` is bitwise complement).  In your example, it's just swapping the high- and low-order nibbles (4-bit sequences) of `octet`.  You can think of it as a circular rotation of an 8-bit value by 4 bits (with this size and shift amount, left- and right- rotation are equivalent).

Comment: You can look at the intermediate shift results to see how they combine to achieve the result.  If the bits of `octet` are `abcdefgh`, then the first operand of `|` is `0000abcd` and the second operand is `edfg0000`.  When combined with bitwise-OR, the result is `efghabcd`.

Comment: What do you mean with 'collaborate'?  (You could have used `+` instead of `|` here.) Please read about these operators and try things out before asking questions.

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the bitwise OR operator. That's the only meaning of the `|` operator in C.

The left and right shift operators move each 4-bit half of the byte (AKA "nibble") to the opposite half. If you start with

```
0100 | 0001
```

then `octet << 4` results in

```
0001 | 0000
```

and `octet >> 4` results in

```
0000 | 0100
```

Notice that `0000` gets shifted into the other nibble when you do each of these shifts. So when you OR everything together, you just get both shifted nibbles.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Single Pipe | serve as a bitwise OR operator here?

Yes, it is the bitwise OR operator in C.

> How does it collaborate/work with the Shift Operators << and >> in this case?

There's quite a bit going on "between the lines" in this code.

Given some data `0xAB`, the `>> 4` results in `0x0A` and the `<< 4` results in `0xAB0`. It's important to realize that most operators in C come with implicit integer promotion and the shifts are actually carried out on type `int`.

So the `|` operator get operands of type `int` handed to it and `0x0A | 0xAB0` = `0xABA`.

Finally during the return, there is another implicit conversion back to `unsigned char`, known as "lvalue conversion". This works just like assignment with `=`,  where the right operand of `=` is converted to the type of the left operand. In my example this causes the `0xABA` to get truncated into `0xBA`.

This narrowing conversion can be thought as conversion "as if by modulus by 1 more than the max of what the type can hold". That is, 0xABA % (255+1) = 0xBA. Which as it happens is the same thing as discarding everything but the least significant byte.

> Can I replace it with a logical OR operator || or anything else?

No. `||` evaluates its arguments to zero or non-zero and returns the integer `0` or `1` like a Boolean. Whereas bitwise `|` merges the two operands together, just like binary addition. 0001b + 0010b = 0011b for example. So to answer the second part of the question, `+` is often analogous to bitwise OR, but it's more confusing to read code using `+`.